# How to limit people access to my EC2 with their public key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, public-key-encryption

Working on EC2 is a snap, you just download the .pem file, give it the right permissions, and you are ready to go, yet ... if you have the .pem file you have full access to the EC2 instance!!

What shall I do to limit people's access to the instance in a controllable way, e.g. people pass me their public key and add it to the instance `a la Github`

Comment: Your question is not clear. DO you want multiple users to access the instance with their own key?

Comment: @helloV, Thanks. With the same .pem key passed to everyone, but I need to have more control who can have access and who cannot. And I suggested something  like they generate ssh keys on their machines and pass me their public key, then I allow them based on this. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible but with different user name. Users will create their keypair and give you the public key. Is that something you want? But each user will have their own account just like GitHub.

Comment: You mean the other users should have different AWS access accounts?

Comment: That's the case actually

Comment: The other users have their own AWS accounts, and I want to share with them my EC2 instance

Comment: No, they need have an account on the EC2 instance, you create a user name for them. Whether they have AWS account or not doesn't matter

Comment: Ok, nice, can you please pass me any reference on how to do it?

Comment: See Robbie Averill's answer to my similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386738/add-a-public-ssh-key-to-an-aws-ec2-running-instance/34386796#34386796

Comment: @tumblingdice, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps in this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

There are 3 steps:

- You have to add a user account (adduser) for each user
- Make sure the user-home/.ssh dir has 600 permission (chmod)
- Add the user public key to user-home/.ssh/authorized_keys and make sure it has 700 permission (chmod)

Comment: and the public key the users generate on their computers, right?

Comment: Yes. They use their private key (ssh -i <private-key> user@host) to access the instance.