# Add a public ssh key to an AWS EC2 running instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to add my friend's public SSH key to a running AWS EC2 instance. How do I go about doing this on a Mac?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250659/how-to-limit-people-access-to-my-ec2-with-their-public-key/34254856#34254856

Comment: See Robbie Averill's answer

Comment: Voted to reopen because "too broad - there are too many possible answers or too long..." is incorrect for this question - there's only one answer, and it's very short.

Comment: @RobbieAverill: It's still off-topic for stackoverflow. Since the question already has an answer, migrating it to a site where it is on-topic serves no purpose (see [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/205381)).

Comment: I'd class linux as a programming tool, i.e. "*directly involve[s] programming or programming tools*"

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy:

1. SSH into your EC2 instance
2. Copy your friend's public SSH key
3. Add it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Example:

```
ssh ec2-user@your-ec2-instance # optional: -i ~/.ssh/YourPrivateKey.pem
echo "PASTE YOUR KEY HERE" >> authorized_keys
```

It'd be useful to ensure your friend's key has a descriptive comment on it, so that when you view `authorized_keys` you don't just see the key and "user-1234@mac-local" or something as the comment - "YourFriend" would be better.